# How to prevent malicious *.js scripts from executing in Node.js

Tags: node.js, security, module

I'm using Node.js to create the web service. In the implementation, I consumed many third party modules which are installed via npm. There is security issue if there is malicious *.js scripts in the consumed modules. For example, the malicious code may delete all my disk files, or collect the secret data in silence.

I have a couple of questions regarding this.

1. How to detect if there is security issue in the module?
2. What should I do to prevent malicious *.js scripts from executing in Node.js?

I'm very appreciate if you can share any experience to build the node.js service.

Thanks,
Jeffrey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One concern you did not raise is that a module might try to make a direct connection to your database itself, or to other services on your internal network.  This might be prevented by setting passwords which the module cannot find so easily.

**1. Restricting disk access**

This project was presented at NodeConf last year.  It attempts to restrict filesystem access in precisely the situation you describe.

https://github.com/yahoo/fs-lock

*"The goal for this module is to help when you are loading 3rd party modules and you need to restrict their access."*

It sounds rather like the proposal Jeffrey made in the comments in Plato's answer.

(If you want to look further into hooking OS calls, this [hookit project](https://github.com/CrabDude/hookit) may present a few ideas.  Although in its current form it only wraps the callback function, it might provide inspiration of what to hook, and how.  Here is [an example](https://github.com/CrabDude/trycatch/blob/master/lib/trycatch.js#L245) of it being used.)

**2. Analyse flow of sensitive data**

If you are only worried about data-stealing (not filesystem or database access), then you can focus your concerns:

- You should be most concerned about those packages which are being passed **sensitive** data.  Presumably some of the data on your web-service is presented to the public anyway!
- Most packages will not have access to the full stack of your application, only the bits of data you pass them.  If a package is only being passed a small amount of sensitive data, and never passed the rest of the data, it may not be able to do anything malicious with the data it receives.  (For example, if you pass all your *usernames* to one package for processing and all your *addresses* to a different package, that is a much smaller concern than if you pass all your *usernames*, *addresses* and *credit-card numbers* to the same package!)
- Identify the sensitive data in your app, and note which functions in which modules they are passed to.

**3. Perform efficient code review**

You may not need to go to Github to read the code.  The great majority of packages provide all their source-code in their install folder inside `node_modules`.  (There are a few packages which provide binaries however; these are naturally harder to verify.)

If you do want to check the code yourself, there may ways to reduce the amount of work involved:

- To secure your own app, you do not need to read the **entire** source code of **all** packages in your project.  You only need to review those functions which are actually called.
- You may trace the code by reading it, or with the aid of [a text-based debugger](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html), or a [GUI debugger](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector).  (Of course you should look out for branching, where different inputs may cause different parts of the module to be called.)
- Set breakpoints when you call into a module which you don't trust, so you can step through the code that is called and see what it does.  You may be able to conclude that only a small part of the module is used, so only that code needs to be verified.
- Whilst tracing flow should cover concerns about sensitive data at runtime, to check for file access or database access, we should also look at the **initialisation** code of each module which is required, and all calls (including `require`s) which are made from there.

**4. Other measures**

It might be wise to lock the version number of each package in `package.json` so that you don't accidentally install a new version of a package until you decide that you need to.

You may use social factors to build confidence in a package.  Check the respectability of the author.  Who is he, and who does he work for?  Do the author and his employers have a reputation to uphold?  Similarly, who uses his project?  If the package is very popular, and used by industry giants, it is likely that others have already reviewed the code.

You may wish to visit github and enable notifications for all the top-level modules you are using, by "watching" the repository.  This will inform you if any vulnerabilities are reported in the package in future.

Comment: You can get notifications about packages with **vulnerabilities** (not necessarily malicious) from tools like [Node Security Project](https://nodesecurity.io/tools), [retire.js](http://retirejs.github.io/retire.js/) and [Snyk](https://snyk.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Most (all?) modules have source code available on Github, you can read through the source and look for security problems, or hire a security professional to do the job.

I just take the risk - although I tend to use popular packages with hundreds of commits, active maintenence, and issue lists.

Comment: thank you for sharing your experience. It is huge workload to check the source code of each modules when consume a new one or update the existing ones. I'm thinking about overriding the require function. So that I can intercept the load requests for risky modules like Child Processes, FileSystem, Process, OS, VM. But it can't plug all the holes.

Comment: One idea: you could set up your main application on one machine, and a second app on the second machine. The second app would handle all `require` statements so in case of an exploit, it would (probably) only be able to affect the second machine. The first app would communicate with the second app but not directly `require` anything (except what you need for that communication).

Comment: Even the build tools and their dependencies in my project make up 338 unique packages (no application code). You'd need 10 "security professionals" to audit them. Even though I think auditing is a good idea, it's stupid to tell `N` companies to employ people for auditing same version of one package again and again. The problem lies in the npm ecosystem. One just need to register at npmjs.com and upload their package. Auditing has to start there. The servers may be insecure so a hacker may change packages. Because they have no signatures it's not possible to detect changes.

Answer (score 0):

If your project dependency tree is large enough, reviewing all of your dependencies is not a feasible long-term strategy.

The original answer from Joey has some good countermeasures you can use for specific scenarios. I've also seen https://github.com/berstend/node-safe - could make you slightly safer on mac.

A general solution to the problem is taking shape though.

### How to protect a project from malicious packages

1. make sure you don't run lifecycle (postinstall) scripts unless they're known and necessary (see my [talk on this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2p1e7UmGYY))
2. put 3rdparty code in a compartment, lock down the environment, decide on which powerful APIs to pass to each package.

The second step requires the use of Compartment, which is a work-in-progress in TC39 https://github.com/tc39/proposal-compartments/

But a shim exists. And Some tooling was built on top of that shim.

You could use the [SES-shim](https://github.com/endojs/endo/tree/master/packages/ses) directly and implement your own controls, or use the convenience of [LavaMoat](https://github.com/LavaMoat/LavaMoat#how-to-secure-your-app-against-supplychain-attacks)

[LavaMoat](https://github.com/LavaMoat/LavaMoat#how-to-secure-your-app-against-supplychain-attacks) lets you generate and tweak a per-package policy where you can decide which globals and builtins it should have access to.
LavaMoat also offers a tool to manage install scripts.

Here's my [talk on SES and LavaMoat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qjeh7Qo2u28) with a demo at the end.

### How to set up LavaMoat

*See LavaMoat docs for more details*

1. disable/allow dependency lifecycle scripts (eg. "postinstall") via @lavamoat/allow-scripts

```
npm i --ignore-scripts -D @lavamoat/allow-scripts
npx --no-install allow-scripts setup
npx --no-install allow-scripts auto
```

- then, edit the allow-list in package.json
- after every insstall/reinstall run `allow-scripts`

3. run your server or build process in lavamoat-node

```
npm i -D lavamoat
```

in your package.json add something like:

```
"scripts": {
  "lavamoat-policy": "lavamoat app.js --autopolicy",
  "start": "lavamoat app.js"
```

- run lavamoat-policy every time you make changes to your dependency tree and review the policy (see also: policy override)
- run `npm start` to start your app

---

> Disclaimer: I contribute to LavaMoat and Endo. They are Open Source projects on permissive licenses.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using virtualization in this case.
I prefer containerization in this case via Docker
You can run docker images with pre-installed build tools (node, etc and mount working directory as volume

For example (change port, node version for your needs):

```bash
docker run --rm -it \
  -v "$PWD:$PWD" \
  -w "$PWD" \
  -p "127.0.0.1:9000:9000" "node:18" bash
```